# Copied range from Excel to Word (Font settings set as hidden?)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a code for copying range of data from Excel to Word. Process works but I have just noticed that copied table is not visible in printing mode, in MS Word. After investigations I have found that Font settings are set to "hidden". This should be coming while copy - pasting process. How it can be fixed? I would like to have it visible `.Font.Hidden = False`

Problem has to be somewhere here `rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False`?

My code from Excel for copy - paste:

```
Case "table2"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices").Range("Q17:V26").Copy
  With wdRng
    Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
    rngPara.Style = wdStyleNormal
    rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Tables(.Tables.Count).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    Set rngPara = Nothing
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `.Font.Hidden = 0`

```
Case "table2"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices").Range("Q17:V26").Copy
  With wdRng
    Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
    rngPara.Style = wdStyleNormal
    rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Tables(.Tables.Count).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    .Font.Hidden = 0
    Set rngPara = Nothing
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Source of the font set to 'hidden' seems to be that Excel Worksheet is set to either `xlSheetHidden` or `xlSheetVeryHidden`. Your solution `.Font.Hidden = 0` works perfectly.

This fixed my problem with Excel tables copied to Word suddenly missing when exported to PDF.

So thank you, I was losing my mind with this.